# begin from the left in \multicolumn

Tags: tables

I have a a table with footnotes that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to start `Year_month` and `The dependent` from the left, such as `* p < 0.1` does. My code is as follows:

```latex
\bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\shortstack{ $^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$. 
\cite{white1980heteroskedasticity} robust SEs in parentheses clustered on a district level.  \\
Year\textunderscore month dummy, weekday \& holidays dummy and district dummy. \\
The dependent variable is the number of robberies per 1.000.000 population.}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I do it, please?

Comment: The horizontal alignment you observe is not related to the use of `\multicolumn` but cause by `\shortstack` whose default horizontal alignment is centerd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an educated guess, a width of 80% of the text width is good enough to accommodate the footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A table caption explaining what it's about}

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c c c c @{}}
\toprule
N & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 \\
Pseudo $\mathrm R^2$ & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}\footnotesize
  $^{*}$ $p<0.1$; $^{**}$ $p<0.05$; $^{***}$ $p<0.01$.

  \cite{white1980heteroskedasticity} robust SEs in parentheses clustered on a district level.

  Year\textunderscore month dummy, weekday \& holidays dummy and district dummy.

  The dependent variable is the number of robberies per 1\,000\,000 population.
\end{minipage}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a bit more work we can make the two parts the same exact width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}

\newsavebox{\tablefootnotebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A table caption explaining what it's about}

% we set the footnotes
\sbox{\tablefootnotebox}{%
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  $^{*}$ $p<0.1$; $^{**}$ $p<0.05$; $^{***}$ $p<0.01$.\\
  \cite{white1980heteroskedasticity} robust SEs in parentheses clustered on a district level.\\
  Year\textunderscore month dummy, weekday \& holidays dummy and district dummy.\\
  The dependent variable is the number of robberies per 1\,000\,000 population.
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tabular*}{\wd\tablefootnotebox}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c c c c @{}}
\toprule
N & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 \\
Pseudo $\mathrm R^2$ & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}

\usebox{\tablefootnotebox}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You also can use the `makecell` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{6em}*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    N & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 & 451185 \\
    Pseudo $\mathrm R^2$ & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
    \bottomrule\addlinespace[2pt]
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize
    \makecell[l]{$^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$.
    \cite{white1980heteroskedasticity} robust SEs in parentheses clustered on a district level.\\
    Year\textunderscore month dummy, weekday \& holidays dummy and district dummy.\\
    The dependent variable is the number of robberies per 1.000.000 population.}}
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can see nothing wrong with using three separate `\multicolumn` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize 
$^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$. 
\cite{white1980heteroskedasticity} robust SEs in parentheses clustered on a district level.}\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize
Year\textunderscore month dummy, weekday \& holidays dummy and district dummy.}\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize
The dependent variable is the number of robberies per 1.000.000 population.} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```